# Installing a light on a beam

Tags: wiring, lighting, led

Previous owner cut into this beam and ran wires through for a light. Beam is 3.5" wide.
[image]

I want to put a flush mount LED light like the one below, but I don't have room for the junction box. Could I just wire this up directly without the junction box and PCB that has components for the switching of colors?
[image]

Comment: If you pull those wires further out of the ceiling do you have access to where they are still inside their outer insulation?   Also, it looks like a faux beam, are you able to remove it?  Or are you willing to break open (and refinish) a patch of ceiling near this location for the junction box?  Or, thinking differently, do you have access to the other end of the cable that's sticking out of the beam?  If so you could use it as a low voltage cable.

Comment: The PCB in the box is more than just "components for the switching of colors". It's the driver electronics for the LEDs which turn the mains AC into a constant-current DC. The LEDs will not operate without all that stuff ( not for more than a few milliseconds anyway before they let their smoke out...).

Comment: You need to sort out whether those wires are properly part of a double insulated cable.  If they are, another option is to purchase similar light without a separate junction box. They do make 120V LED wafer lights where the electronics are arranged flatly as part of the light housing, and they make them in all kinds of shapes and styles.  It won't be as flat or flush as this one but you won't see that if it's up on a ridge beam.

Comment: What's above the ceiling?

Comment: The wires are part of a double insulated cable, I can see it. But that makes sense. I think what I need is just what you said @jay613 , a 120V LED so I don't have to deal with the junction box.

Comment: Does anyone have a good 120V light suggestion that will fit within the 3.5" beam without sticking out? Preferably square in shape and black in color

Comment: Shopping questions aren't allowed here, but just to set you in the right direction here's a [4x4x3/4](https://www.build.com/afx-egsf0407l30d1/s1628120?uid=3865498) one.   Search your favorite site for "panel light" then filter by size.  Note you'll still need a normal round ceiling box to attach these to.  You could mount it on the beam, which will increase the depth accordingly, or maybe in the beam, if it's a faux one, by drilling those holes out to a proper 3 inch or 4 inch opening for a ceiling box.

Comment: Again, if you can  find the other end of the cable and put the LED drivers THERE, you can install 12V or 24V lights screwed directly to the beam with no junction box at all.  That might involve a little work chopping a new junction box into a wall, but that'll be easier than putting one in the beam.

Answer (score 3):

The big question is where do the wires split from the cable. The cable is supposed to go into the box. Get up there with a flashlight and see if the end of the cable is reachable. If it isn't then you need to run a new cable. But if it is reachable:

- Cut a box size rectangle around the existing crazy holes. Might be easiest with a reciprocating saw.
- Mount a box inside the beam.
- Cable goes into wall of box (side or back, whatever works) with separate wires inside the box.
- Depending on box and light fixture, you may need an adapter plate as a box cover.
- Mount a **UL or ETL listed light fixture**. Unlisted foreign junk is OK if it runs off low voltage from a listed transformer. But not OK directly attached to 120V AC.

Answer (score 1):

I *really* hope that beam is decorative, not structural... You might want to make sure of that.

Generally, code requires connections be made inside a box, for fire safety and maintainability both. However, I *have* seen some splicing connectors recently that claim to be approved for unenclosed use. I don't know enough about them to know whether they would be approved for your application.

Not knowing what's inside the box they show, I have no idea whether that would do the job for you or not